# How to write a cron expression for 10th weekday of the month?

Tags: cron

I am a novice in the field pf CRON Expression. I want to write one for the 10th Workday (Business Day) of the month.

I have already tried out [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html#cronexpressionexamples) site to help me out with the expressions. Couldn't help myself with this.

Comment: I don't think that's possible using pure cron expressions. Some parsers (Quartz?) may support a syntax like `0 0 0 10W * ? *` for "The weekday closest to the 10th day of the month", but that's still probably not what you want to achieve, right?

Comment: Please define business day? Monday-Friday, no exceptions?

Comment: @user871611 no requirement. It just have to be 10th business day.

Comment: And again, how do you define a business day? Business days are different all over the world.

Comment: As I mentioned, 10th weekday of every month.

Comment: Be kind. That's always what I say and preach. :) @user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a CRON job that runs daily. You can then nest your functionality in an if clause, such as:

```
if (isTenthWeekday()) {
    //your functionality
}

private boolean isTenthWeekday() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int sumWeekdays = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); i++) {
        Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
        d.set(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), i);
        if (d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) > 1 && d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) <= 6) {
            sumWeekdays++;
        }
    }
    return sumWeekdays == 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
+---------------- minute (0 - 59)
|  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
|  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
|  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
|  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
|  |  |  |  |
*  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

This is the matrix. For the use of workdays (maybe exclude holidays etc. you need to rewrite the script for these days)

Comment: How to exclude holidays in this matrix?

Comment: As far as i know u can not exclude holidays, you need to know when the holliday is and the rewrite the script for your needs. e.g. execute one day befor / after the holiday and then undo the changes afterwards. Just write a method which recognize holdays and do the magic for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try with below cron expression it will execute on every 10th day of month.If it is weekday then only cron will work as I have assumed (MON-FRI) as business days.Please try and ask for further any help

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 10 1-5 ?")
public void scheduletask() {
    // ...
}
```

thnkx.

Comment: This means "At 12:00 PM, on day 10 of the month, January through May".

Comment: yes you can change your start time.I t will work for whole year not from Jan to may.As 1-5 means it will work for weekdays only (MON-FRI).

Comment: https://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/?expression=0+0+12+10+1-5+%3F&locale=en external sources seem to disagree

Comment: AS PER YOUR EXTERNAL source the expression would be                                    
                          "0 0 12 10 *  ?  MON-FRI"

Comment: The two expressions you have suggested are different to each other: "0 0 12 10 1-5 ?" vs "0 0 12 10 * ? MON-FRI". The first one runs every 10th of the month (regardless if it's the 10th working day or not) and the second one runs every weekday. In any case, none of them does what the OP asked.